# Android ListView on update goes to top then to the correct position

Tags: android, listview, position

I'm using a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter. 
The List is an infinite scroll of tweets. 
Updates to the list are inserted from the top.
I want to obtain an effect as the Twitter application. I'm not talking about the "scroll to update", but to maintain the position after the update.

I've just implemented some code that works in that way. Here it is:

```
        // get the position of the first visible tweet.
        // pausedCounter traces the number of tweets in the waiting line
        final int idx = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + pausedCounter;
        View first = listView.getChildAt(0);
        int position = 0;


        if (first != null)
            position = first.getTop();

        // here I update the listView with the new elements
        for (Tweet[] tweets1 : pausedTweets)
            super.updateTweets(tweets1);


        final int finalPosition = position;

        // this code maintain the position
        listView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.setSelectionFromTop(idx, finalPosition);
            }
        });
```

The problem of this code is that for an instant the listView goes to the first element of the list, then kick in the *setSelectionFromTop* and it goes to the correct position.

This sort of "flickering" is annoying, and I want to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out only this solution:

```
        // add the new elements to the current ArrayAdapter
        for (Tweet[] tweets1 : pausedTweets)
            super.updateTweets(tweets1);

        // create a NEW ArrayAdapter using the data of the current used ArrayAdapter
        // (this is a custom constructor, creates an ArrayAdapter using the data from the passed)
        TweetArrayAdapter newTweetArrayAdapter =
                new TweetArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.tweet_linearlayout, (TweetArrayAdapter)listView.getAdapter());

        // change the ArrayAdapter of the listView with the NEW ArrayAdapter
        listView.setAdapter(newTweetArrayAdapter);

        // set the position. Remember to add as offset the number of new elements inserted
        listView.setSelectionFromTop(idx, position);
```

In this way I have no "flickering" at all!